# c++ undefined reference to 'class::function()'

Tags: c++, class

As explained above i have a problem making classes.I am getting this error:

`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\ccj3stv6.o    main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to 'plate::plate()'`

`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\ccj3stv6.o    main.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to 'plate::SayHello()'`

`E:\c++\proje16\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status`

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "plate.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    plate pobj;
    pobj.SayHello();
}
```

plate.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "plate.h"

using namespace std;


plate::plate(){
}

void plate::SayHello () {
    cout << "hello";
}
```

plate.h

```
#ifndef PLATE_H
#define PLATE_H

class plate
{
    public:
        plate();
        void SayHello();
};

#endif
```

[error,main.cpp,plate.cpp,plate.h combined as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLcfP.png)

using `#include "plate.cpp"` instead of `#include "plate.h"` helps but i am not sure if thats a good fix or not.

I am using dev-c++ 5.11.I am not that experienced in coding.I done some research before posting this question but couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: Do you have the `plate` files included as part of your project, so that they're compiled and linked together with your main?

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579172/undefined-reference-to-class-constructor-including-cpp-file-fixes) similar issue.

Comment: Your constructor is useless.

Comment: i didnt do anything but it is working now :P do i have to restart my computer after making a new class or something? @manni66 is that an issue?

Comment: It's a readability issue.